# UIAlertView and UIAlertController IOS 9

Tags: uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm editing a project IOS8 to IOS 9, I have difficulty in finding UIAlertView that in IOS 9 tells me he is "DEPRECATED"
I have now replaced UIAlertView with UIAlertController but I find other errors,
can anyone help me solve this problem?
Thank You!

This is my code

```html
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    Annotation *myAnnotation = (Annotation *)view.annotation;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentUserCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, myMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, myAnnotation.coordinate.longitude);
    
    if ((CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coord))&&(CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(currentUserCoords))) {
        Annotation *ann = (Annotation *)view.annotation;
        selectedCoords = ann.coordinate;
        
        NSString *strTitle = @"GPS";
        NSString *strMess = @"Close and open in maps?";
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:strTitle
                                                        message:strMess
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                                                        message:@"It was not possible to determine the current location.\nPlease check in: /nSettings> Privacy> Location"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];
    if (!pinView) {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        
        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.intValue >= 7)
            pinView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.743 green:0.609 blue:0.432 alpha:1.000];
        
        
    } else {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

I tried to replace UIAlertView with UIAlertController.
here is the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzWJA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike UIAlertView, UIAlertController declaration is little different and straightforward.
Here is a sample declaration -

```
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Any Title" message:@"Any Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *anyAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ActionName" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    //Any relevant method you want to call
    }];

    //Adding the alert action
    [alert addAction:anyAction];

    //Presenting the AlertController
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For Advance implementation details you can refer to one of my sample implementation [here](https://github.com/Sameeran92/POCs-/tree/AlertControllerPOC/AlertController%20Trial)